# How to add a href with a specific scroll amount

Tags: html, css, scroll

So I know that you can link hrefs to sections with ids

example=

```
<a id="example1">example</div>
<a id="example2" href=#example1>example2>
```

which makes the text "example2" scroll to "example1" when clicked, but I was wondering if there was a way to make it so its a amount of scroll not necessarily to a id. More context: I have sections on my website and when I make it to the id it goes a bit to high so how do I make it lower.

PS: sorry im really bad at explaining and i hope its understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at [this article](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/) for two easy methods.

#### Here is one of the methods they suggested:

HTML

```
<a id="example1">example</div>
<a id="example2" href=#example1>example2>
```

CSS

```
#example1::before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using the id to scroll between sections also works fine.

```html
<a id="example1">example</a>
<br />
<a id="example2" href=#example1>example2</a>
```

And if it scroll little bit higher to the position,  you can style it like this also https://snippets.cacher.io/snippet/8de5c03cae9ceb8d4c64